# Web scraping with Nightmare Cloud function works locally, but not when deployed

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, nightmare

I am trying to scrape a JavaScript calendar and return a JSON array of its events in Google Cloud Functions (Blaze plan). The below function works, but only when ran locally through the Firebase emulators. It deploys successfully, but every call causes a timeout. No errors were thrown in the logs or anything. Both the local and deployed functions running on Node.js 10. (**EDIT**: I found [this](https://www.linode.com/docs/development/nodejs/use-nightmarejs-to-automate-headless-browsing/) article mentioning xvfb is required to use Nightmare without a display, but I'm not sure how I would add that to Firebase, or even install it)

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const Nightmare = require('nightmare'); //latest version   

const retrieveEventsOpts = { memory: "2GB", timeoutSeconds: 60 };
exports.retrieveEventsArray = functions.runWith(retrieveEventsOpts).https.onRequest(async (request, response) => {
  nightmare = Nightmare({show: false})

  try {
    await nightmare
      .goto('https://www.csbcsaints.org/calendar')
      .evaluate(() => document.querySelector('body').innerHTML )
      .then(firstResponse => {
        let responseJSON = parseHTMLForEvents(firstResponse) //Just a function that synchronously parses the HTML string to a JSON array
        return response.status(200).json(responseJSON)
      }).catch(error => {
        return response.status(500).json(error)
      })
  } catch(error) {
    return response.status(500).json(error)
  }
})
```

Comment: You might not want to mix async/await with then/catch callbacks.  That might be messing up your expected error handling.  This can be done entirely with try/catch/await.  You also might want to add some logging statements to see exactly what is or is not being executed the way you expect.

Comment: Where would the log statements be printed? When run locally it shows up in Terminal, but there’s nothing like that once deployed. And would you mind putting the try/catch/await pattern in an answer? I’m not entirely sure how I would implement that. Thanks